# What is the correct way to add a property of specific items from a different array to an object

Tags: angularjs

I have two different arrays, one holds `categories` whilst the other holds `pages`.

Categories array:

```
$scope.categories = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Test category"
}];
```

Pages array:

```
$scope.pages = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Test page",
  category: 1
}];
```

I would like to add all associated pages to its category. This can be achieved by knowing if the `category` property for a page is equal to a category's `id`.

At the moment, I wrote a function which loops through

```
function getPagesById(categoryId) {

  var tmp = [];

  for (var i = $scope.pages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if($scope.pages[i].category == categoryId) {
      tmp.push($scope.pages[i]);
    }
  };

 return tmp;

}

function mergePages() {

  var tmp = $scope.categories;

  for (var i = tmp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    tmp[i].pages = getPagesById(tmp[i].id);

  };

  return tmp;

}

$scope.categories = mergePages();
```

Is this the correct Angular way to achieve this?

Comment: The solution you are proposing is working, right ?

Comment: Yes, its more "I don't think i'm doing it the best way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer to this. If I interpret your question as 'Can Angular simplify this?' then yes, it can.

You can use Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to condense your `mergePages` function into something like this:

```
function mergePages()
{
    angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category)
    {
        category['pages'] = $filter('filter')($scope.pages, {category: category.id});
    });
}
```

This will populate `$scope.categories` with the appropriate pages by comparing the category ids in the filter.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3690/) a fiddle that demonstrates it working.

Comment: Totally forgot about using a filter, thank you! Its defiantly a lot more simple and clean...